# What are Macbook Charge Cycles?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charge

Okay so i dont know what a cycle is.

Can you tell me that if I leave my macbook on charge all night, so at our place there our power outages so when my mac will start charging after the power comes back on will 1 cycle increase?

Answer (score 1):

A charge cycle is defined as 1 full discharge and 1 full recharge.   It is defined in the [UN Manual of Tests and Criteria, Subsection 38.3](https://www.gefahrgut-online.de/fm/3578/Kap_38_3_neu.pdf):

> Cycle means  one  sequence  of  fully  charging  and  fully 
>   discharging  a  rechargeable cell or battery.

This means that if you only discharge your battery 20% and recharge it, you would have do to it 5 times to be a full cycle.  A 50% drain and recharge would have to happen twice to be considered a cycle.  And so on.

So in reference to your question, unless your battery fully drained, you didn't go through a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You create charging cycles based on how you handle draining and charging your MacBook battery. The most efficient way to handle charging cycles is to allow your MacBook to drain completely before charging it to 100%.

A typical MacBook battery is supposed to give you 1000 charging cycles until the battery reaches 80% of its original charging capacity. You can get the most charging capacity out of your battery by handling your charging cycles correctly as I described in the paragraph above.

I hope this helps your understanding of how charging cycles work.

EDIT: Think [link](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html) should help