# Understanding Mac Battery Information

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, power-management

In System Information, we can obtain information about the battery, e.g.:

```
Battery Information:

  Model Information:
    Serial Number:  D866192Q1NFFWLKE1
    Manufacturer:   SMP
    Device Name:    bq20z451
    Pack Lot Code:  0
    PCB Lot Code:   0
    Firmware Version:   702
    Hardware Revision:  1
    Cell Revision:  3241
  Charge Information:
    Charge Remaining (mAh): 8681
    Fully Charged:  No
    Charging:   No
    Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 9199
  Health Information:
    Cycle Count:    4
    Condition:  Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    -1131
  Voltage (mV): 12817
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    -1131
  Voltage (mV): 12817
```

I'd like to know:

- What does the `Cell Revision` field mean?
- How are `Cycle counts` calculated?

Comment: Cycle counts has been explained here:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233751/119271

Comment: As far as the "Cell Revision", as far as I can tell, it's a manufacturing code related to the testing and certification of the battery cells:  http://www.metlabs.com/battery/un-38-3-transportation-testing-required-for-lithium-battery-safety-during-shipping/

Answer (score 1):

Every time you fully charge your macbook battery it counts as 1. to count 1 cycle you will have to charge unto 100%. That 100% can be charged in 1 time or you can charge 20% 5 different times.